# How to prevent Windows 10 from waking HDD just because I move the mouse?

Tags: windows-10, power-management

Hardware:

- Intel Core i7-6700
- ASUS H170M-PLUS motherboard (i.e. Intel H170 chipset)
- Boot partition and user profiles on Intel SSDPEKKW25 NVMe (256 GB SSD)
- Toshiba DT01ACA300 HDD (3TB SATA hard disk for bulk storage)

OS: Windows 10 Pro 64-bit

Problem:
Windows puts the Toshiba HDD to sleep after idle timeout, which is nice. However, as soon as I move the mouse, Windows wakes up the Toshiba HDD, even though I don't think anything immediately needs to use that HDD.

I have *some* programs installed on that HDD, mostly modern games that take up lots of space.

Is there a way to prevent Windows from immediately waking up that HDD when I move the mouse?

Answer (score 0):

Go to Device Manager. Locate your mouse. Right click. Click properties. If the checkbox next to Allow device to wake computer from sleep is checked, uncheck it. That should fix it!

Comment: Isn't the mouse, not the HDD, that is waking the HDD and computer? I don't see how the HDD is waking up the computer.

Comment: @El8dN8 your comment and downvote are misleading. I disabled Allow device to wake computer from sleep setting for my mouse and keyboard and my laptop doesn't wake up anymore